# c#: How does List.Add() actually adds new item to array internally?

Tags: c#, list

I am courious to know how List.Add actually works ? internally it stores items in array. but array can't be resized once created. So far I can imagine only way could be creating a new aray and copy all the values of old array and resizing it. ut how does this work ? I am tryig to recreate List.Add but I don't know how to make it work like real one.

Comment: "So far I can imagine only way could be creating a new aray and copy all the values of old array and resizing it" yes that is basically how it's done under the hood. Please show a [mcve] of your attempt to implement your own `List`, so we can tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: just look at the source-code: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs

Comment: Yes, basically that's how it's done. But typically such collections don't do that one by one, but for instance double the capacity of the array everytime it's newly allocated.

Comment: You might want to read wikipedias article on [Dynamic Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array), that is the computer science term for List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [source-code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs):

```
// Adds the given object to the end of this list. The size of the list is
// increased by one. If required, the capacity of the list is doubled
// before adding the new element.
//
public void Add(T item) {
    if (_size == _items.Length) EnsureCapacity(_size + 1);
    _items[_size++] = item;
    _version++;
}

private void EnsureCapacity(int min) {
    if (_items.Length < min) {
        int newCapacity = _items.Length == 0? _defaultCapacity : _items.Length * 2;
    // Allow the list to grow to maximum possible capacity (~2G elements) before encountering overflow.
    // Note that this check works even when _items.Length overflowed thanks to the (uint) cast
    if ((uint)newCapacity > Array.MaxArrayLength) 
        newCapacity = Array.MaxArrayLength;
    if (newCapacity < min) newCapacity = min;
        Capacity = newCapacity;
}
```

You see it just adds items to the internal array until its size is reached. So not every item needs a resize. When the max size is reached, the array will be recreated with a doubled size, so you can add more than only a single item per resize.

Comment: Thanks , what is role of the version here ?